# Key mapping for converting `((` to `\left( | \right)`

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, replace, plugin-vimtex

I would like to have something in `.vimrc` where when I type `((` in insert mode, it automatically converts that into `\left( | \right)` with the cursor position at `|` in insert mode. Any ideas?

I also would like this feature to be enabled when `Filetype` is `tex`.

Comment: Running macros always starts with the `@` key. Do you mean a key mapping?

Comment: Something I can define in `.vimrc` and only applied when the filetype is `tex`, that if I type `((` in insert mode, it converts it into `\left( | \right)` with cursor at `|`.

Comment: Sounds like a key mapping.

Comment: Yeah keymapping it is then!

Comment: I would take a look at the [Ultisnips plugin](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-ultisnips/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `~/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`, put

```
inoremap <buffer> (( \left(  \right)<C-o>T(<space>
```

Don't forget to adjust `b:undo_ftplugin` (`:help undo_ftplugin`). I use a [helper function for the task](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/autoload/bk/ftplugin.vim).

Comment: why can't I just use 
`autocmd FileType tex inoremap (( \left(  \right)<C-o>T(<space>` ?

Comment: @Tom you _can_. I don't recommend it. The reasons are detailed, but the short versions are: maintainability, readability, flexibility, performance, and not re-inventing the wheel. Plus, as I said, `b:undo_ftplugin`.

Comment: What is `b:undo_ftplugin`? Where do I have to put it? Before or after?

Comment: @Tom cf `:help undo_ftplugin`. I usually put it at the end of my ftplugin file, though I have a helper to get the right value, since I usually want to extend what may already be there.

Comment: May be editing the answer?

Comment: I think you want to use `<buffer>` argument for the inoremap

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt yes, thank you

Comment: @Tom is there some reason you unaccepted the answer? I'm happy to make improvements if something is not working for you.

Comment: Opps, my bad, I think I miss clicked it when I was copying and paste the code!